# How to trigger data validation only when user click on submit form but not after value changing in textbox in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations

I have one model with some attributes inside such as CustomerName.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer Name is required")]
public string CustomerName{ get; set; }
```

In my form, I declare the text box like following:

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerName).ID("txtCustomerName"))
```

When I first load the page, there will be data loaded into the txtCustomerName. Besides, there is another button which have the function to clear the value of the text box. However, once I click the clear button, the error message "Customer Name is required" show up immediately since the data annotation attribute is stated "Required".

My question is how do I avoid the validation being triggered when the text box value is cleared programmatically? Of course when click on submit form, the validation will be triggered which is ok. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more efficient way to do this (I'm fairly new to ASP-NET Data Annotations myself), however this is how I would tackle it:

Remove the Required annotation from your CustomerName string in your model if you don't want a validator to appear when the field value is removed.

Define the field for the CustomerName like so:

```html
<input id="txtCustomerName" onchange="$('#txtCustomerNameValidator').hide()" type="text" asp-for="CustomerName">
<!--Validation span, feel free to customise this with CSS as you wish -->
<span id="txtCustomerNameValidator" style="display: none;">Please Enter a Customer Name</span>

<!-- Make sure a button in your form is set up to call the JS method: -->
<button type="submit" onclick="OnCustomerFormSubmit('formId')">Submit Form</button>
```

The `asp-for` tag helper is incredibly useful for referencing a variable/object value in your Page Model and maintaining it's value if it has one.

Make a JS method that will show/hide some validation when you submit your form for that field and have it fire when you click your submit button:

```js
function OnCustomerFormSubmit(formId) {
    var customerNameField = $("#txtCustomerName");
    var customerNameValidator = $("#txtCustomerNameValidator");
    var isValid = true;

    if (customerNameField.val() === null || customerNameField.val() === '') {
        customerNameValidator.show();
        isValid = false;
    }

    if (isValid) {
        $('#' + formId).submit();
    }
}
```

If anyone has any improvements they could suggest for this approach, that would be great. Be gentle haha.

I hope this helps you out OP.

Comment: Hi @JJ173, thanks for your reply. But I wonder where can I get "#txtCustomerNameValidator"? No such element found.

Comment: Hi @JCYOUNG, try adding this snippet under your Customer Name Input Field: 

`<span id="txtCustomerNameValidator" style="display:none;">     
    <span id="txtCustomerName_Error">Please Enter a Customer Name</span> </span> `

That should give you your desired output and display the error that you want.

You should add a CSS class to the txtCustomerNameValidator span tag as well if you want it to look like the errors from the Data Annotations. You should be able to find the class you want if you inspect an error element and take the class from that.